# How do I get this css to work with my html?

Tags: html, css

I’m following a tutorial that uses html, css and JavaScript to create a portfolio however none of the css rules are working. When I inspect the page it shows all the css crossed out with warning signs next to them. What can I do?

```css
/*==================== GOOGLE FONTS =======================*/
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@400;500;600&display=swap");
  
/*==================== VARIABLES CSS =======================*/
    :root {
    --header-height: 3 rem;

  /*=========== Colors ============*/
  /* change fovorite color */
  --hue-color: 142; /*Purple 250 - Green 142 - Blue 230 - Pink 340*/

  /* HSL color made */
  --first-color: hsl(var(--hue-color), 69%, 61%);
  --first-color-second: hsl(var(--hue-color), 69%, 61%);
  --first-color-alt: hsl(var(--hue-color), 57%, 53%);
  --first-color-lighter: hsl(var(--hue-color), 92%, 85%);
  --title-color: hsl(var(--hue-color), 8%, 15%);
  --text-color: hsl(var(--hue-color), 8%, 45%);
  --text-color-light: hsl(var(--hue-color), 8%, 65%);
  --input-color: hsl(var(--hue-color), 70%, 96%);
  --body-color: hsl(var(--hue-color), 60%, 99%);
  --container-color: #fff;



  /*============= Font and typography ===============*/
  --body-font: 'Poppins', sans-serif;

  /* .5rem = 8px, 1rem = 16px, 1.5rem = 24px ... */
   --big-font-size: 2rem;
   --h1-font-size: 1.5rem;
   --h2-font-size: 1.25rem;
   --h3-font-size: 1.125rem;
   --normal-font-size: .938rem;
   --small-font-size: .813rem;
   --smaller-font-size: .75rem;

   /*============ Font Weight ==============*/ 
   --font-medium: 500;
   --font-semi-bold: 600; 


   /*======== Margenes Bottom =============*/
   /* .25rem = 4px, .5rem = 8px, .75rem = 12px ... */
    --mb-0-25: .25rem;
    --mb-0-5: .5rem;
    --mb-0-75: .75rem;
    --mb-1: 1rem;
    --mb-1-5: 1.5rem;
    --mb-2: 2rem;
    --mb-2-5: 2.5rem;
    --mb-3: 3rem; 

    /*============ Z index =============*/
    --z-tooltip: 10;
    --z-fixed: 100;
    --z-model: 1000;


    /* font size for large devices */ 
    @media screen and {min-width: 968px {
        :root {
            --big-font-size: 3rem;
            --h1-font-size: 2.25rem;
            --h2-font-size: 1.5rem;
            --h3-font-size: 1.25rem;
            --normal-font-size: 1rem;
            --small-font-size: .875rem;
            --smaller-font-size: .813rem;
        }
    }


/*============== Variables Dark theme ================*/


/*=============== Button Dark/Light ===================*/



/*========================= BASE ========================*/
*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

html{
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

body{
    margin: 0 0 var(--header-height) 0;
    font-family: var(--body-font);
    font-size: var(--normal-font-size);
    background-color: var(--body-color);
    color: var(--text-color);
}

h1,h2,h3,h4{
    color: var(--title-color);
    font-weight: var(--font-semi-bold);
}

ul{
    list-style: none;
}

a{
    text-decoration: none;
}

img{
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

/*================ REUSABLE CSS CLASSES ================*/
.section{
    padding: 2rem 0 4rem;
}

.section__title{
    font-size: var(--h1-font-size);
}

.section__subtitle{
    display: block;
    font-size:var(--small-font-size);
    margin-bottom: var(--mb-3);
}

.section__title,
.section__subtitle{
    text-align: center;
}

/*========================= LAYOUT =======================*/
.container{
    max-width: 768px;
    margin-left: var(--mb-1-5)
    margin-right: var(--mb-1-5)
}

.grid{
    display: grid;
    gap: 1.5rem;
}

.header{
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: var(--z-fixed);
    background-color: var(--body-color);
}


/*========================== NAV =========================*/
.nav{
    max-width: 968;
    height: var(--header-height);
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between; 
    align-items: center;
}

.nav__logo, 
.nav__toggle{
    color: var(--title-color);
    font-weight: var(--font-medium);
}

.nav__logo:hover{
    color: var(--first-color);
}

.nav__toggle{
    font-size: 1.1rem;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.nav__toggle:hover;
    color: var(--first-color);

@media screen and (max-width: 767px){
    .nav__menu{
        position: fixed;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        background-color: (--body-color);
        padding: 2rem 1.5rem 4rem;
        box-shadow: 0 -1px 4px rgba(0,0,0,.15);
    }
}




    /* show menu */


/* Active Link */
    














    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <!/--============= UNICONS =================-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unicons.iconscout.com/release/v3.0.6/css/line.css">

    <!/--============= SWIPER CSS ==============-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="" />

    <!/--================= CSS ======================-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="myportfolio.css">
    <title>Responsive Portfolio Website</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!/--================== HEADER ======================-->
    <header class="header" id="header">
        <nav class="nav container">
          <a href="#" class="nav__logo">Randy</a>

          <div class="nav__menu" id="nav-menu"></div>
              <ul class="nav__list grid">
                  <li class="nav__item">
                    <a href="#Home" class="nav__link">
                      <i class="uil uil-estate"></i> Home
                    </a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav__item">
                    <a href="#About" class="nav__link">
                      <i class="uil uil-user"></i> About
                    </a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav__item">
                    <a href="#Skills" class="nav__link">
                      <i class="uil uil-file-alt"></i> Skills
                    </a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav__item">
                    <a href="#Services" class="nav__link">
                      <i class="uil uil-briefcase"></i> Services
                    </a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav__item">
                    <a href="#Portfolio" class="nav__link">
                      <i class="uil uil-scenery"></i> Portfolio
                    </a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav__item">
                    <a href="#Contact" class="nav__link">
                      <i class="uil uil-message"></i> Contact Me
                    </a>
                  </li>
              </ul>
              <i class="uil uil-times nav__close" id="nav-close"></i>
            </div>

            <div.nav="nav__btns">
              <div class="nav__toggle" id="nav-toggle"></div>
              <i class="uil uil-apps"></i>
          </nav>
    </header>
    <!/--=================== MAIN ========================-->
    <main class="main">...</main>

    <!/--=================== FOOTER ======================-->

    <!/--=================== SCROLL TOP ====================-->

    <!/--==================== SWIPER JS ====================-->
    <script src=""></script>

    <!/--==================== MAIN JS ======================-->
    <script src=""></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is the tutorial:
https://youtu.be/27JtRAI3QO8

[inspected page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PGpiU.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GmJoG.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LVBUU.jpg)

Comment: Please edit the question, use the snippet tool `<>` and post the code here.

Comment: is the css file name correct?

Comment: yes it is i ctr + click and made sure it was right

Comment: it says the css codes are invalid so im not sure why. every browser loads it like this and i cant figure it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your css file had some issues

```css
/*==================== GOOGLE FONTS =======================*/
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@400;500;600&display=swap");
  
/*==================== VARIABLES CSS =======================*/
    :root {
    --header-height: 3 rem;

  /*=========== Colors ============*/
  /* change fovorite color */
  --hue-color: 142; /*Purple 250 - Green 142 - Blue 230 - Pink 340*/

  /* HSL color made */
  --first-color: hsl(var(--hue-color), 69%, 61%);
  --first-color-second: hsl(var(--hue-color), 69%, 61%);
  --first-color-alt: hsl(var(--hue-color), 57%, 53%);
  --first-color-lighter: hsl(var(--hue-color), 92%, 85%);
  --title-color: hsl(var(--hue-color), 8%, 15%);
  --text-color: hsl(var(--hue-color), 8%, 45%);
  --text-color-light: hsl(var(--hue-color), 8%, 65%);
  --input-color: hsl(var(--hue-color), 70%, 96%);
  --body-color: hsl(var(--hue-color), 60%, 99%);
  --container-color: #fff;



  /*============= Font and typography ===============*/
  --body-font: 'Poppins', sans-serif;

  /* .5rem = 8px, 1rem = 16px, 1.5rem = 24px ... */
   --big-font-size: 2rem;
   --h1-font-size: 1.5rem;
   --h2-font-size: 1.25rem;
   --h3-font-size: 1.125rem;
   --normal-font-size: .938rem;
   --small-font-size: .813rem;
   --smaller-font-size: .75rem;

   /*============ Font Weight ==============*/ 
   --font-medium: 500;
   --font-semi-bold: 600; 


   /*======== Margenes Bottom =============*/
   /* .25rem = 4px, .5rem = 8px, .75rem = 12px ... */
    --mb-0-25: .25rem;
    --mb-0-5: .5rem;
    --mb-0-75: .75rem;
    --mb-1: 1rem;
    --mb-1-5: 1.5rem;
    --mb-2: 2rem;
    --mb-2-5: 2.5rem;
    --mb-3: 3rem; 

    /*============ Z index =============*/
    --z-tooltip: 10;
    --z-fixed: 100;
    --z-model: 1000;

}
    /* font size for large devices */ 
    @media screen and (min-width: 968px) {
        :root {
            --big-font-size: 3rem;
            --h1-font-size: 2.25rem;
            --h2-font-size: 1.5rem;
            --h3-font-size: 1.25rem;
            --normal-font-size: 1rem;
            --small-font-size: .875rem;
            --smaller-font-size: .813rem;
        }
    }
    

/*============== Variables Dark theme ================*/


/*=============== Button Dark/Light ===================*/



/*========================= BASE ========================*/
*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

html{
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

body{
    margin: 0 0 var(--header-height) 0;
    font-family: var(--body-font);
    font-size: var(--normal-font-size);
    background-color: var(--body-color);
    color: var(--text-color);
}

h1,h2,h3,h4{
    color: var(--title-color);
    font-weight: var(--font-semi-bold);
}

ul{
    list-style: none;
}

a{
    text-decoration: none;
}

img{
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

/*================ REUSABLE CSS CLASSES ================*/
.section{
    padding: 2rem 0 4rem;
}

.section__title{
    font-size: var(--h1-font-size);
}

.section__subtitle{
    display: block;
    font-size:var(--small-font-size);
    margin-bottom: var(--mb-3);
}

.section__title,
.section__subtitle{
    text-align: center;
}

/*========================= LAYOUT =======================*/
.container{
    max-width: 768px;
    margin-left: var(--mb-1-5);
    margin-right: var(--mb-1-5);
}

.grid{
    display: grid;
    gap: 1.5rem;
}

.header{
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: var(--z-fixed);
    background-color: var(--body-color);
}


/*========================== NAV =========================*/
.nav{
    max-width: 968;
    height: var(--header-height);
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between; 
    align-items: center;
}

.nav__logo, 
.nav__toggle{
    color: var(--title-color);
    font-weight: var(--font-medium);
}

.nav__logo:hover{
    color: var(--first-color);
}

.nav__toggle{
    font-size: 1.1rem;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.nav__toggle:hover;
    color: var(--first-color);

@media screen and (max-width: 767px){
    .nav__menu{
        position: fixed;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        background-color: (--body-color);
        padding: 2rem 1.5rem 4rem;
        box-shadow: 0 -1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
    }
}




    /* show menu */


/* Active Link */
```

```html
 <header class="header" id="header">
        <nav class="nav container">
          <a href="#" class="nav__logo">Randy</a>

          <div class="nav__menu" id="nav-menu"></div>
              <ul class="nav__list grid">
                  <li class="nav__item">
                    <a href="#Home" class="nav__link">
                      <i class="uil uil-estate"></i> Home
                    </a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav__item">
                    <a href="#About" class="nav__link">
                      <i class="uil uil-user"></i> About
                    </a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav__item">
                    <a href="#Skills" class="nav__link">
                      <i class="uil uil-file-alt"></i> Skills
                    </a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav__item">
                    <a href="#Services" class="nav__link">
                      <i class="uil uil-briefcase"></i> Services
                    </a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav__item">
                    <a href="#Portfolio" class="nav__link">
                      <i class="uil uil-scenery"></i> Portfolio
                    </a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav__item">
                    <a href="#Contact" class="nav__link">
                      <i class="uil uil-message"></i> Contact Me
                    </a>
                  </li>
              </ul>
              <i class="uil uil-times nav__close" id="nav-close"></i>
            </div>

            <div.nav="nav__btns">
              <div class="nav__toggle" id="nav-toggle"></div>
              <i class="uil uil-apps"></i>
          </nav>
    </header>
```

Comment: how did you fix that?? looks so much better

Comment: your css file had some issues. 1. the root class didn't have any closing tags...2. in your media query you weren't using any brackets around the screen size...for these errors your style wasn't applying.

Comment: also some properties didn't have `;` after them...that's why the next line wasn't being read

Comment: wow i was going crazy. i was stuck on this for at least a day. thank you so much for the help!

Comment: yes of course my bad this is my first time using this site

Answer (score 0):

Class names can not start with two hyphens.  So, remove one hyphen from them.

> There are a couple of predefined rules that should be followed while choosing the class name or selectors.
>
> 1. All CSS syntax is case-insensitive with in the range of [a-z] and [A-Z].
> 2. CSS classes, element name and IDs can contain only the characters [a-zA-Z0-9] , hyphen (-) and the underscore (_).
> 3. selectors cannot start with a digit, two hyphens, or a hyphen followed by a digit.
> 4. selectors can have # and . along with \

From [tutorial schools](https://tutorialschools.com/Html/which-characters-are-valid-in-CSS-class-names-selectors)

Comment: so all the css rules arent working because the class names have the (--) before it? im not sure why the video does it that way

Comment: That's right.  Not everything on the internet is correct.  Change one and prove it yourself.  The tutorial I found suggested that this was a good way to disable a spec in the css